# Catch dynamic page without use database ID

Tags: php

This is my `content.php`. I want to show `sectors/sector_id=1.php` if some one click one my side bar `sectors/sector_id=1.php` then sector pass an ID 1 then it shows some content then another menu then it goes to another page, but it shows only one page `sector_id=0.php` and when ID is 1 or 2 it shows `sector_id=0.php` this page:

```
<?php
    if($id==1) include('sectors/sector_id=1.php');
    if($id==2) include('sectors/sector_id=0.php');
?>
```

This is my side bar

```
<ul id="sector-nav" class="nav"> 
    <li >
        <!--<a href="&Itemid=&sector_id=1">Fibre</a>-->
        <a href="sectors.php?<?php echo $id=1; ;?>">Fibre</a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <!--<a href="&Itemid=&sector_id=2">Hand Protection</a>-->
        <a href="sectors.php?<?php echo $id=2; ?>">Hand Protection</a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <!--<a href="&Itemid=&sector_id=3">Purification Products</a>-->
        <a href="sector_id=3.html">Purification Products</a>
    </li>
    <!-- others <li>'s -->
</ul>
```

Comment: this `sectors.php?<?php echo $id=2; ?>` won't give you the URL you need... by the way, how are you getting the `$id` ?

Comment: i want to show different content in a page which is come by if loop but how can it possible i don't know any suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you're trying to pass the variables. If you're Link is:

`<a href="sectors.php?1">Fibre</a>`

This will not get through to your PHP the way you want. I would advise creating the link like so:

`<a href="sectors.php?id=1">Fibre</a>`

When this link is followed, sectors.php will be able to get that value from `$_GET['id']` variable. You can then do:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    include('sectors/sector_id=' . $_GET['id'] . '.php');
}
?>
```

Now, if you do something like:

`<a href="sectors.php?1">Fibre</a>`

This can be used too, but will generate a NULL value at the index called 1, `$_GET['1']`. So you could grab the Key versus the value if you wanted.

Comment: Great. If this has answered your question, I hope you will mark it as the answer.

Comment: i cant mark it it says reputation must be 15 but i have only 1 and i am new so thanks for your help